# tkinter ttk Entry widget callback works only once

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I discovered a strange behaviour with tkinter ttk.Entry when bundled.
On both of my machines the .exe works without a problem, even in different locations.

But on another laptop (Windows 10) one Entry widget doesn't work properly:

```
entry_article = ttk.Entry(main_frame, textvariable=article_number,
                                  justify=tk.LEFT,
                                  width=20,
                                  font=self.data['total_price'])
entry_article.bind('<Return>', click_next)
entry_article.bind('<space>', click_new)
```

So on Return it should click next, empty the widget, so that you can proceed.
this will be called only once. after that.. it doesnt work anymore.

```
   def click_next(e):

        if current_sale_id.get() == '':
            sale = new_sale()
        else:
            sale = Sale().get_by_id(current_sale_id.get())

        if article_number.get() == '':
            mb.showerror('Kein Artikel eingetragen', 'Bitte Artikelnummer eintragen')
        else:
            sell_article(sale, article_number.get())
        entry_article.delete(0, 'end')

    def click_new(e):
        new_sale()
        tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
        entry_article.delete(0, 'end')
```

I just dont know, why it works on both of my machines, but on another laptop it executes only once.

Comment: Please make sure your code is a [mcve].

Comment: When it doesn't work, is it because focus has shifted to another widget or another app?

Comment: There is nothing in your code indicating such behavior. However, a common pitfall is that you replace bounded commands when not explicitly stated that you want to `add` it to existing ones.

Comment: Are you using MacOS on laptop? Or some other pycharm, pytorch, etc